# How to write for loop when function increases with each iteration?

Tags: r, for-loop, winbugs, jags

I am trying to estimate the probability of detecting animals from n.sites over multiple observation periods when animals are removed and detection changes in time and space. It works if I do something like this for 5 observation periods:

```
for(i in 1:nsites){
  mu[i,1] <- p[i,1]
  mu[i,2] <- p[i,2]*(1-p[i,1])
  mu[i,3] <- p[i,3]*(1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])
  mu[i,4] <- p[i,4]*(1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])
  mu[i,5] <- p[i,5]*(1-p[i,1])*(1-p[i,2])*(1-p[i,3])*(1-p[i,4])
}
```

The probability at time 2 is dependent on the probability at time 1 and the probability at time 3 is dependent on the probabilities at times 1 and 2. If I were only doing this for 5 time periods it wouldn't be a big deal to write this out. But as I get 10, 15, 20+ time periods, it's is quite messy to write out. I feel like there should be a way to write this loop without typing out each step, but I just can't think of how to do it. Maybe additional indexing or other control statement or power function. If p[i] were the same in each jth observation (i.e. p[i,1] = p[i,2] = p[i,3], etc.) it would be:

```
p[i]*(1-p[i])^5
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is BUGS language code. I work in R and sent the code to JAGS via the rjags package. BUGS, R, or pseudo code would suit my purposes.

Here is R code that would simulate the problem:

```
set.seed(123)
testp <- matrix(runif(108, 0.1, 0.5), 108, 5)
testmu <- matrix(NA, 108, 5)

for(i in 1:nsites){
  testmu[i,1] <- testp[i,1]
  testmu[i,2] <- testp[i,2]*(1-testp[i,1])
  testmu[i,3] <- testp[i,3]*(1-testp[i,1])*(1-testp[i,2])
  testmu[i,4] <- testp[i,4]*(1-testp[i,1])*(1-testp[i,2])*(1-testp[i,3])
  testmu[i,5] <- testp[i,5]*(1-testp[i,1])*(1-testp[i,2])*(1-testp[i,3])*(1-testp[i,4])
}
```

Thanks for any help.
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Frank's answer is cleaner (and faster, probably), but this will also work and might be a little easier to understand.

```
testmu2 <- matrix(NA, 108, 5)
nsites = 108
np = 5

for (i in 1:nsites) {
  fac <- 1
  testmu2[i,1] <- testp[i,1]
  for (j in 2:np) {
    fac <- fac * (1-testp[i,j-1])
    testmu2[i,j] <- testp[i,j] * fac
  }
}
max(abs(testmu2-testmu))
[1] 2.775558e-17
```

Comment: +1. I don't know if it's easier to read, but I might write the inner loop's body as `testmu2[i,j] <- testp[i,j]*(fac <- fac * (1-testp[i,j-1]))`

Comment: @Frank - I didn't even know you could use two assignments on one line. Thanks #somuchtolearn

Comment: You were correct in your estimates of speed. Frank's method was ten times faster than yours or mine.

Comment: I chose this because it's more general (doesn't use R specific functions). It may still have an issue in BUGS language because fac is being reassigned, but I hopefully can work around that.

Answer (score 4):

This really does look like a task well suited to R's `Reduce`:

```
testmu3 <- matrix(NA, 108, 5)
nsites = 108
np = 5

for (i in 1:nsites) {
   testmu3[ i, ] <- Reduce( function(x,y) x*(1-y), testp[i, ], 
                                                   accumulate=TRUE)
}
max(abs(testmu3-testmu))
[1] 0
```

The accumulate parameter creates a growing vector of intermediate results.

```
> testp[1, ]
[1] 0.215031 0.215031 0.215031 0.215031 0.215031

> Reduce( function(x,y) x*(1-y), testp[1, ],  accumulate=TRUE)
[1] 0.21503101 0.16879267 0.13249701 0.10400605 0.08164152
```

Comment: +1, Cool. I didn't know about that `accumulate` option, even though I use `Reduce` quite a lot. For the OP's reference... the loop could be eliminated here, too, using `t(apply(testp,1,function(z) Reduce( function(x,y) x*(1-y),z,accumulate=TRUE)))`

Comment: I actually never heard of the Reduce function before. Very neat. Thanks for the answer as well as the new function!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
testmu2 <- testp*t(apply(cbind(1,1-testp[,-5]),1,cumprod))
```

On my computer, they almost match:

```
> max(abs(testmu2-testmu))
[1] 2.775558e-17
```

I don't know about BUGS/JAGS, but the idea is to take the cumulative product of your 1-p matrix across its columns first, and then take p*result.

Comment: Very slick, thank you. I still have trouble wrapping my head around the apply function. For loops are much more natural for me, but the apply function is so much faster.